# Carbon's addMonths is being called 2 times in Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-livewire

Im building a project in Livewire. Now i need to show an attendance page. So far it is working fine, but it works only for the current months(as it should). My idea is to show the previous and upcoming months attendance sheet. My code will generate attendance sheet for the students of the given group only once in the first day of the current month and will generate for new added students in case they haven't been added before. But now i just want to show the previos month and upcoming month(so it should not generate attendance sheet and yeah it is working as i wanted so far). But the problem rises when i click to show previous or upcoming month attendance - instead of being called only once, it calls the function 2 times. I've configured alpine and livewire styles/scripts as it should be, but still the function is being called 2 times, here's code. the backend functions that does this named `changeMonth` and also i did log that function activity, i will it at the end.

blade:

```
    <div>
    <div class="relative overflow-x-auto shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
        <div class="flex justify-between mb-4">
            <button wire:click.prevent="changeMonth(-1)">Previous Month</button>
            <div>
                <label for="monthSelector">Select Month:</label>
                <input type="month" id="monthSelector" wire:model="selectedMonth" />
            </div>
            <button wire:click.prevent="changeMonth(1)">Next Month</button>
        </div>
        @json($selectedMonth)
        <table class="w-full text-sm text-left rtl:text-right text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
            <thead class="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                    {{ __('Name') }}
                </th>
                @foreach($monthDays as $day)
                    <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                        {{ $day }}
                    </th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach( $students as $student )
                <tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
                    <th scope="row" class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                        {{ $student->name }}
                    </th>
                    @foreach($monthDaysDate as $day)
                        <td class="px-6 py-4">
                            <div class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                                @php
                                    $attendance = $student->attendance->where('date', $day)->first();
                                    $isPresent = $attendance ? $attendance->is_present : false;
                                    $isDefaultStatus = $attendance ? $attendance->is_default_status : true;
                                @endphp

                                @if ($attendance)
                                    @if ($isPresent && !$isDefaultStatus)
                                        <button wire:click="updateAttendance('{{ $student->id }}', '{{ $day }}', 'false', '{{ $student->name }}')"
                                            class="py-0.5 px-2 text-sm bg-green-500 text-white rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-green-300 hover:bg-green-600">
                                            +
                                        </button>
                                    @elseif (!$isPresent && !$isDefaultStatus)
                                        <button wire:click="updateAttendance('{{ $student->id }}', '{{ $day }}', 'true', '{{ $student->name }}')"
                                            class="py-0.5 px-2 text-sm bg-red-700 text-white rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-red-300 hover:bg-red-800">
                                            -
                                        </button>
                                    @else
                                        <button wire:click="updateAttendance('{{ $student->id }}', '{{ $day }}', 'true', '{{ $student->name }}')"
                                                class="py-0.5 px-1.5 text-sm bg-yellow-500 text-white rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-yellow-300 hover:bg-yellow-600">
                                            ...
                                        </button>
                                    @endif
                                @else
                                    <!-- Handle the case where no attendance record is found for the specified date -->
                                    <span>{{ __('No attendance record') }}</span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

backend:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Livewire\Teacher\Attendance;

use App\Models\Attendance;
use App\Models\Group;
use App\Models\Student;
use Livewire\Attributes\Lazy;
use Livewire\Component;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Usernotnull\Toast\Concerns\WireToast;

#[Lazy]
class ShowGroupAttendance extends Component
{
    use WireToast;

    public $groupId;
    public $groupDays, $monthDays, $monthDaysDate, $createAttendanceRecordsFlag = false, $selectedMonth;

    public function mount($id)
    {
        $this->groupId = Group::find($id);
        $this->groupDays = json_decode($this->groupId->days_in_week, true);
        $this->generateMonthDays();

        $this->selectedMonth = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m');
        $currentMonth = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m');

        // Check if attendance records exist for the current month
        if (!$this->groupId->attendanceRecordsExistForMonth($currentMonth)) {
            // Set a flag to ensure that records are only created once during the initial render
            $this->createAttendanceRecordsFlag = true;

            // Create attendance records for each student
            $students = $this->groupId->students;

            foreach ($students as $student) {
                $this->createAttendanceRecord($student, $currentMonth);
            }
        } else {
            $this->createMissingAttendanceRecords($currentMonth);
        }
    }

    private function createMissingAttendanceRecords($currentMonth)
    {
        // Get the existing users for the group
        $existingUsers = $this->groupId->students->pluck('id')->toArray();

        // Get the users for whom attendance records have been created
        $usersWithAttendanceRecords = $this->groupId->attendance()
            ->whereYear('date', Carbon::parse($currentMonth)->year)
            ->whereMonth('date', Carbon::parse($currentMonth)->month)
            ->pluck('student_id')
            ->toArray();

        // Find the new users that need attendance records
        $newUsers = array_diff($existingUsers, $usersWithAttendanceRecords);

        // Create attendance records for new users
        foreach ($newUsers as $userId) {
            $student = Student::find($userId);
            $this->createAttendanceRecord($student, $currentMonth);
        }

        toast()
            ->success( '', 'Attendance is added with new students for ' . date('F'))
            ->duration(2500)
            ->push();
    }

    private function createAttendanceRecord($student, $currentMonth)
    {
        $groupDays = $this->groupDays;

        // Loop through each day of the week specified for the group
        foreach ($groupDays as $dayOfWeek) {
            $firstDayOfMonth = Carbon::createFromDate($currentMonth, 1);

            $difference = ($dayOfWeek - $firstDayOfMonth->dayOfWeek + 7) % 7;

            $date = $firstDayOfMonth->copy()->addDays($difference);

            // Check if the date is within the current month
            while ($date->month == Carbon::parse($currentMonth)->month) {
                $existingRecord = $this->groupId->attendance()
                    ->where('student_id', $student->id)
                    ->where('date', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
                    ->exists();

                if (!$existingRecord) {
                    $this->groupId->attendance()->create([
                        'student_id' => $student->id,
                        'date' => $date->copy(), // Copy the date to avoid modifying the original
                        'is_present' => false,
                        'is_default_status' => true,
                    ]);
                }

                // Move to the next occurrence of the same day of the week
                $date->addWeek();
            }
        }

        toast()
            ->success( '', 'Attendance is created for ' . date('F'))
            ->duration(2500)
            ->push();
    }

    public function updateAttendance( $studentId, $date, $value, $studentName)
    {
        $attendance = Attendance::where('group_id', $this->groupId->id)
            ->where('student_id', $studentId)
            ->where('date', $date)
            ->first();

        if ($attendance) {
            switch ($value) {
                case 'true':
                    $attendance->update([
                        'is_present' => true,
                        'is_default_status' => false,
                    ]);

                    toast()
                        ->success('is marked as in the class', $studentName)
                        ->duration(1000)
                        ->push();
                    break;
                case 'false':
                    $attendance->update([
                        'is_present' => false,
                        'is_default_status' => false,
                    ]);
                    toast()
                        ->danger('is marked as not in the class', $studentName)
                        ->duration(1000)
                        ->push();
                    break;
                default:
                    abort(403);
            }
        }
    }

    private function generateMonthDays()
    {
        $now = Carbon::parse($this->selectedMonth);
        $this->monthDays = [];
        $this->monthDaysDate = [];

        // Calculate the first day of the month
        $firstDayOfMonth = Carbon::create($now->year, $now->month, 1);

        // Loop through each day of the month
        for ($day = 1; $day <= $firstDayOfMonth->daysInMonth; $day++) {
            $currentDate = Carbon::create($now->year, $now->month, $day);

            // Check if the day is in the specified days_in_week array
            if (in_array($currentDate->dayOfWeek, $this->groupDays)) {
                $this->monthDays[] = $currentDate->format('j M');
                $this->monthDaysDate[] = $currentDate->format('Y-m-d');
            }
        }
    }

    public function changeMonth($increment)
    {
        $oldMonth = $this->selectedMonth;
        $this->selectedMonth = Carbon::parse($this->selectedMonth)->addMonths($increment)->format('Y-m');
        $newMonth = $this->selectedMonth;

        logger("Old Month: $oldMonth, New Month: $newMonth");

        $this->generateMonthDays();
    }

    public function placeholder()
    {
        return view('livewire.teacher.placeholder.groups');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $students = $this->groupId->students;

        return view('livewire.teacher.attendance.show-group-attendance', [
            'students' => $students,
            'monthDays' => $this->monthDays,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and for any case models

group model:

```
    class Group extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'subject_id', 'teacher_id', 'group_fee', 'days_in_week', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'color',
    ];

    public function teacher()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class);
    }

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
    }

    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class, 'subject_id');
    }

    public function totalStudents()
    {
        return $this->students->count();
    }

    public function getStudentsBySubjects()
    {
        $subjectIds = $this->subjects()->pluck('id')->toArray();

        return Student::whereHas('subjects', function ($query) use ($subjectIds) {
            $query->whereIn('subject_id', $subjectIds);
        })->get();
    }

    public function attendance()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attendance::class);
    }

    public function attendanceRecordsExistForMonth($month)
    {
        return $this->attendance()
            ->whereYear('date', Carbon::parse($month)->year)
            ->whereMonth('date', Carbon::parse($month)->month)
            ->exists();
    }
}
```

attendance model:

```
    class Attendance extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'group_id', 'student_id', 'date', 'is_present', 'is_default_status',
    ];

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }

    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
    }

}
```

and i tried to log my function and here's log file part:

```
[2023-11-27 16:05:23] local.DEBUG: Old Month: 2023-11, New Month: 2023-10  
[2023-11-27 16:05:23] local.DEBUG: Old Month: 2023-10, New Month: 2023-09
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue causing this. It is just the `#[Lazy]` attibute. I dont know why it is causing this, but after removing it, everything worked as needed. before that i did some nasty code, but now everything is working. hope that livewire team will solve this

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `Livewire` has a problem distinguishing similar buttons in its logic. Seems like adding `wire:key` directive can prevent this, if you look at this [issue](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/763).

```
<button wire:key="previousMonth" wire:click.prevent="changeMonth(-1)">Previous Month</button>
...
<button wire:key="nextMonth" wire:click.prevent="changeMonth(1)">Next Month</button>
```

Comment: nope, that didn't solve the issue